# Getting the End Date given the Start Date and range

Tags: javascript, date

Suppose I having the current computer date which I have code below:

```
// Current date declaration
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var currentDate = ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' + ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + d.getFullYear();
```

How can I get the End Date when a date range is given?

Example:

CurrentDate : 24/12/2013

Date Range : 30 days

The output of End Date should be : 23/01/2014

Can anyone share your solution?

Comment: Can you share your thoughts first? Any reason to be `currentDate` variable a string?

Comment: Hint: use a timestamp.

Comment: @zerkms  The solution of finding currentDate I find out from one of the question has been asked in this website also. I does have the concept of finding the endDate, because I search the question from this website, I found all of them are trying to find the date range given the start date and end date.

Comment: @user3107399: so, you don't have any personal thoughts? Only thoughts of other people?

Comment: @zerkms   Nope. I have tried create other function about the PHP. And because I still new in PHP. I have try to learn something in PHP. I just do not have the concept/idea to generate the endDate.

Comment: @user3107399: how would you do it on a piece of paper, manually, if you asked to do so?

Comment: @user3107399: so it does mean that you don't even want to try to understand how to solve such tasks? Okay. Until there are a "programmers" like you - I will always have a job, thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

In `javascript` you can code like this.

```
var time = new Date();
time.setDate(time.getDate()+30);
```

If you need to do this task in `php`, you can use `strtotime()` function

```
 $newDate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 days")); //to get current date and add 30 days to current date.
echo $newDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var currentDate = ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' + ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + d.getFullYear(); 

console.log(currentDate);

var dayRange = 30;

d.setDate(d.getDate() + dayRange);
month = d.getMonth()+1;
day = d.getDate();
year = d.getFullYear();
currentDate = ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' + ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + d.getFullYear(); 

console.log(currentDate);
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6X6PS/

javascript will calculate it for you automate

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score -1):

Ok, changed it for JS

```
  var EndDate = new Date(); 
  EndDate.setDate( EndDate.getDate() + 30 );
```

Comment: Have you seen anything about php in the question?

Comment: @zerkms Actually the tag used to be [tag:php] until I changed it.

Comment: @Jeremy: oh I see. Seems like these days reading a title and a list of tags is assumed to be enough to answer. That's funny )

Comment: @zerkmsn It's all about the fastest gun ;)

Answer (score -1):

This helps to get end date using days

```
<?php
  //$startdate=$_POST['sd'];
  $startdate='2013-12-25';
  $date=date_create($startdate);
  date_add($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("10 days"));
  echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
  ?>
```